# Decrypting SSL/TLS traffic from a app with Wireshark

Tags: ssl, networking, ssl-certificate, wireshark, tls1.2

I have a pcap file with has the TLSv2.0 traffic from an Windows exe application.

I also have the backend server's private key used to establish the connection.

I have tried both the enabling ssllogfile environment variable and also tried selecting the private key under Wireshark -> Preferences -> TLS. But I still could not decrypt the traffic.

Is there any other way?

The cipher suite used is TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256

Comment: "I also have the backend server's private key used to establish the connection." This is not enough to decrypt after the fact some TLS exchanges as session keys are generated during the exchange, if you do not store them at that point, they are lost later. Your question is also not about programming, so offtopic here. Probably look instead at [su] and do a search first, there are tons of questions about Wireshark and TLS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "ECDHE" means the key exchange is done using Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman, which provides forward secrecy. This means that the private key from the server X.509 cert is not enough to decrypt the traffic. You will need to get the client application to generate an SSLKEYLOGFILE, which can be done with Chrome, Firefox and curl. If the "Windows exe application" is something different, then you'll have to intercept the TLS traffic in order to see what goes inside the TLS tunnel.

If you wanna analyze the decrypted traffic in Wireshark, then I'd recommend to proxy the traffic with [PolarProxy](https://www.netresec.com/?page=PolarProxy), because it generates a PCAP file with the decrypted traffic from the TLS session. You will not need any SSLKEYLOGFILE if you choose to intercept and decrypt the TLS traffic with PolarProxy.

Comment: So I installed PolarProxy onto a ubuntu system and on the windows platform I specified the IP of the ubuntu system and port 10443 under the windows' system's proxy settings.

Now when I run the applications over at PolarProxy i am getting:

"SYSTEM.IO.IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format." error.

I have installed the PolarProxy cert as trusted root certs in both the windows platform.

Any idea where I have gone wrong?

Comment: @aandroidtest Please note that PolarProxy is a transparent proxy, which means that you don't need to configure any proxy setting in the client application (or in the OS for that matter). The only thing that matters is that the TLS traffic (like the HTTPS traffic on TCP 443) is routed via the PolarProxy machine.

Comment: @aandroidtest: Make sure you're following the instructions in the section named "Routing HTTPS Traffic to the Proxy" here:
https://www.netresec.com/?page=PolarProxy

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Any idea how do I get polarproxy to use the ip in the client hosts file when doing dns resolving? Or it is not possible?

Comment: @aandroidtest PolarProxy will look for the Server Name Indication (SNI) extension in the client's TLS handshake. If an SNI is found, then PolarProxy will do a host lookup to find the IP to connect the external TLS session to. If the domain shouldn't be resolved via DNS, then simply add the IP to the Ubuntu PC's /etc/resolv.conf file.

However, if the client doesn't send any SNI, then you can use the "--nosni 10.1.2.3" argument to have PolarProxy connect to the IP 10.1.2.3.

Run "./PolarProxy --help" for more details.

Comment: @aandroidtest to avoid `SYSTEM.IO.IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.` error, I did it the newbie way: stopped my nginx service to free the port 443, and used the 1st example in the [tutorial](https://www.netresec.com/?page=PolarProxy), avoiding the routing part.

Comment: Did you by any chance configure configure proxy settings in the browser or OS? PolarProxy is a *transparent* proxy, which means that the browser should be configured as if there was no proxy (except for the root cert). The "REDIRECT" firewall rule will ensure that the HTTPS traffic goes to PolarProxy.

What happens if you run:
`curl --insecure --connect-to website.com:443:[polarproxy-ip]:443 https://website.com/` ?